# Partial regression plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, regression

I'm quite new to R and I would love to get some help with creating a partial regression plot for a research project.

Here is my full model:

```
model2 <- lm(scenarios_anger ~ 1 + scenarios + age + female + politics + relg + spirit, data=data)
```

My goal is to create a scatterplot that only presents the relationship between `scenarios` and `scenarios_anger` while holding all the other predictors constant.

After some asking around, I figured out that I need to 1) create another model predicting `scenarios_anger` from all the other predictors apart from `scenarios`, and then take the residual from this model.
And 2) create a third model predicting `scenarios` from all the other predictors in the full model, then take the residual from this model as well.

I have calculated the residuals as such:

```
model1 <- lm(scenarios_anger ~ 1 + age + female + politics + rely + spirit, data=data)

resid.model1 <- residuals(model1)

model2b <- lm(scenarios ~ 1 + age + female + politics + relg + spirit, data=data)

resid.model2b <- residuals(model2b)
```

The problem is that I can't seem to plug in my residual values into the ggplot function to create the scatterplot. I tried this command:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = resid.model2b, y = resid.model1)) + geom_point(na.rm=T)
```

But I get this error message saying `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (786): x, y`

I wonder if it's because my residuals are not in the right class for the ggplot function? How can I resolve this problem? Or is there another way to create my partial regression plot?

Comment: ggplot only takes a data.frame for its `data` parameter, and the aesthetics you assign in `aes` should be bare column names from that data.frame. Here, you'd need something like `ggplot(data.frame(m1 = residuals(model1), m2b = residuals(model2b)), aes(x = m1, y = m2b)) + geom_point()`

Comment: My advice would be to add all residuals alongside other variables in your original `model1` data.frame. That way, plotting or modelling any one of them is "out of the box" with given R functions for modeling and ggplot2.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thank you for the advice!

Comment: `broom::augment` is a very quick way to add residuals (and fitted values and more) to your data.frame, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the residuals you want to use in the plot are newly created objects that are not in the data frame `data`.  Hence, when you give your `ggplot` command it is looking for residual variables that aren't there.  You should either add the residual variables back into the data frame `data` or create a new data frame with these residuals for the purpose of your plot.  For the latter method, you would do something like this:

```
#Create the residuals (same as in your question)
model1 <- lm(scenarios_anger ~ 1 + age + female + politics + rely + spirit, data=data);
resid.model1 <- residuals(model1);
model2b <- lm(scenarios ~ 1 + age + female + politics + relg + spirit, data=data);
resid.model2b <- residuals(model2b);

#Create new data frame containing those residuals
NEWDF <- data.frame(RES1 = resid.model1, RES2b = resid.model2b);

#Now generate your plot using this NEWDF as your data
library(ggplot2);
ggplot(data = NEWDF, aes(x = resid.model2b, y = resid.model1)) + geom_point(na.rm=T);
```

This should ensure that the variables referenced in `aes` are in the data object being called by `ggplot` and so it should solve your problem.  If you are still getting an error please let me know.